# Mysql Feed to make tables in html/php

Tags: php, mysql

Hello all i have a quick question

Is there a way i could make a php system that could read a mysql database and make multiple tables based on that and new information?

So say if we implemented it and we added new information to the database it would automatically add a new table into the php page or would that have to be done manually

I just wanted to know if it is doable before i start to look deeper into the code of it

Comment: No , It seems ive explained this wrong :

I wish to have a php page that is linked to a mysql database...

I want it to be a dynamic table page so when i add a new row into the mysql database it will generate a html table into the php page for us with the information from the row we have just entered.

Comment: That's what is php (and any other dynamic language) made for

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is doable.

There is nothing that can prevent you from doing that.

Taking into account your comment:
Yes it's still doable. Terribly inefficient but doable. You can use AJAX or COMET to update information on your page.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

Look at [phpMyAdmin](http://www.phpmyadmin.net/home_page/index.php) for an example of what you are talking about.